# Putting a guard on a WPF event trigger. Is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I currently have

```
<ContentControl
   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" 
   >
   <ContentControl.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
           <BeginStoryboard 
               Storyboard="{StaticResource ShakeStatorMinorRadiusEdit}"/>
       </EventTrigger>
   </ContentControl.Triggers>

   ... <snip> ...

</ContentControl>
```

and

```
    <Grid.Resources>
         <Storyboard x:Key="ShakeStatorMinorRadiusEdit">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="StatorMinorRadiusEdit"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X" 
                        RepeatBehavior="5x"
                        >
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="3"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.20" Value="-3"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
     </Grid.Resources>
```

[image]

The idea is that when the mouse enters the yellow highlighted control on the left the yellow highlighted control on the right will shake. The control on the right has the x:Name=`StatorMinorRadiusEdit` So far so good the above works.

Now I want to add another complication. I only want the animation to trigger if a value on my view model RotorLobes == 1. In an imaginary world I would do.

```
<ContentControl
   Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" 
   >
   <ContentControl.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">

           <If Property="{Binding RotorLobes}" Value="1"/>

           <BeginStoryboard 
               Storyboard="{StaticResource ShakeStatorMinorRadiusEdit}"/>
       </EventTrigger>
   </ContentControl.Triggers>

   ... <snip> ...

</ContentControl>
```

In the real world I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer from Mark Green does not work though it was a really good and like try. Probably not a good idea to mark it up any higher people.

Comment: I hope my edited answer gets you a little closer.

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure it gets round the problem I identified. XAML is a pig really. For example it's impossible to define a story board as a static resource and then apply it to a remote element via TargetName in any sensible way.

Comment: I feel your pain. In this case, MVVM is really your friend.  Bind IsMouseOver to a ViewModel property and bind a DataTrigger to a ViewModel property IsMouseOverAndRotorIsOne to trigger the storyboard and this problem becomes simpler as you can then reference the Storyboard in a style that you can apply to the remote element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try changing from an EventTrigger to a MultiTrigger and using the IsMouseOver property rather than the MouseEnter event. However, as you discovered, Storyboards in styles do not allow you to specify a TargetName, so it's important to move the triggers to the target object.

The example below hard-codes the value of Rotor to 1 and you'll need to correctly namespace the RenderTransform in the TargetProperty or you'll get a runtime exception.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="ShakeStatorMinorRadiusEdit">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                               RepeatBehavior="5x">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.05"
                                          Value="0" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1"
                                          Value="3" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15"
                                          Value="0" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.20"
                                          Value="-3" />
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25"
                                          Value="0" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Rotor</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">Stator</TextBlock>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="1">Lobes</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="2">Major Radius</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.Row="3">Minor Radius</TextBlock>

        <TextBox Name="RotorLobes"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Text="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Name="MinorRadiusRotor"
                 Background="Blue"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="3" />

        <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="2" />
        <TextBox Name="MinorRadiusStator"
                 Background="Green"
                 Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="3">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MinorRadiusRotor, Path=IsMouseOver}"
                                           Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=RotorLobes, Path=Text}}"
                                           Value="1" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ShakeStatorMinorRadiusEdit}" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: EnterAction super :)   Not quite the answer to the question of putting a guard on the event but will solve my specific problem.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work for a subtle problem. Because I want to trigger a storyboard and the storyboard needs to use ``Storyboard.TargetName="StatorMinorRadiusEdit`` to refer to the right hand control I get a XAML error saying I can't use ``TargetName`` in a style. When you look into this via google some of the posts say to use EventTriggers instead and then we are back to the original question. Grrrrrrr

Comment: Hope you don't mind. I updated your answer with the fully fleshed out XAML to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing You should add your relevant code to your question, not add it on to Mark's answer. You should let Mark edit his code as needed to fix any issues you may have with it. I rolled it back since, with your edit, the post became more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: His answer is wrong and results in ``compile time / runtime errors``.

Comment: @WillEddins Either the answer should be withdrawn or marked up to show that it is incorrect or fixed. The question is fine as it stands however it requires an understanding that it is problematic to use TargetName within a Style. The fact that the answer has +4 shows people think it is correct without reading the comments that show there is a problem. This is not a criticism of mark green as the answer from a first inspection is a great one. I thought so too till I tried it and found it not to work.

Comment: The changes I think are correct. I came up with a similar solution myself. Defining the animation on the object to be animated and using ElementName to refer to the control where the mouse event should be rather than the other way round was the fix.